# Parse all NS* variables in source using regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract the names of all variables within an objective-c .m file. I thought regex might be a good way to do this. Let's say I have something like this in my source:

```
- (void)testMethod:(NSString*)param1Name param2:(NSString*)param2Name{
    NSxxxxx *xxxx = @"something";
    NSString *test2 = @"test";
    NSArray *array;
}
```

Ideally the output I'm looking for, is something like this:
xxxx
test2
array

Is this doable with regex? I think one regex might be enough to extract all lines with a word that starts with NS when the next word starts with *.

Edit: I have this so far:

```
(NS)\w+\s*?
```

Problem with this is that it matches the type of the var, not the var name:

```
NSXXXXX
NSString
NSArray
```

How can I get this to match the word after the asterisk?

Comment: Sounds feasible. Have you already started on it?

Comment: Still figuring it out. So far I'm thinking (NS)\w+\s\*? Is that the right way?

Comment: Though that'll match the type of the variable, not the actual word after that

Comment: Yes, it looks better than nothing, please update the post with your attempt and describe what's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to match specific occurrences of NS* variables (those at the start of the lines), you may use

```
(?m)^[ \t]*NS\w+\s*\*\s*(\w+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iL4nC6/3)

The value you need will be inside Group 1.

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - Multiline option ON to allow `^` to match the start of a line, not string
- `^` - start of a line
- `[ \t]*`  - zero or more spaces/tabs
- `NS` - a literal text `NS`
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits or underscores)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\*` - an asterisk
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` -  Group 1 - 1+ word chars.

Comment: Is this a perl compatible regex? I thought of either using this with grep, or objective-c. Love the details explaining what each component means. Thanks for that.

Comment: Objective-C uses ICU regex library, and this regex will work in Objective-C. Just do not forget to use double backslashes in the Objective-C string literal.

Comment: Cool, I think I have it working! Thanks again for the explanations Wiktor!